# How to wait subscribe until all finished?

Tags: angular

I have 4 methods and every of method is calling when method before finished. On all of them im setting this: `this.service.next('1');this.service.next('2');this.service.next('3');this.service.next('4');` Im using this to know which method is finished so for example sometimes i will execute only 3 methods sometimes 1 and sometimes all. My problem is that i subscribe on other component but it enter every time in subscribe. What i want is to wait all of methods finished and then call that `this.service.next()`.

In all of methods i have some logic with if else statement.

This is one of my methods:

```
  getOpenConnectionOnLoad(eventSourceId?: any) {
        this.sharedData.block = 'ES';
        this.api.get('/ccm/eventsource/customerESBlock-esId/' + eventSourceId + '?isVpn=true')
            .subscribe(results => {
                this.eventSourceInfo = results['payload'].eventsources[0];
                Object.assign(this.sharedData.customer.eventSourceInfo, this.eventSourceInfo);
                this.setConnectionIds();
                this.customerNames = results['payload'];
                Object.assign(this.sharedData.customer.customerNames, this.customerNames);
                if (this.eventSourceInfo.saggId) {
                    this.openSagg(0, this.eventSourceInfo.saggId);
                }
                if (this.eventSourceInfo.baggId) {
                    this.getBaggById(this.eventSourceInfo.baggId);
                }
                this.showEs();
                this.sharedData.customer.show = 7;

                this.sharedData.callservice.next('2');
            });
```

In other component i have this:

```
   this.sharedData.callservice.subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('entry ');
        });
```

I want then entery only once and not 4 times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at **forkjoin** operator:

This operator makes all the api calls passed as arguments and will resume when all return data.

```
Observable.forkJoin([
        this.http.get('https://your/api/call/1'),
        this.http.get('https://your/api/call/2'),
 ]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] is our result of first api call
  // results[1] is our result of second api call
  console.log(results[1]);
  console.log(results[0]);
});
```

#### Update (thanks to @HameedSyed)

In rxjs version 6+ the syntax changed:

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

return forkJoin(
    this.http.get('https://your/api/call/1'),
    this.http.get('https://your/api/call/2'));
```